# How can get a full subtraction of time of these two time values in SSRS?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I currently have two time values in two separate expressions in SSRS which I would like to subtract one from the other to give me a sub total time.

At present value 1 is of 163:02:38 and the expression is as follows:

```
=System.Math.Floor(Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value) / 3600) & ":" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

While value 2 is of 5:12:46

```
=System.Math.Floor(Sum(Fields!Time_in_Default.Value) / 3600) & ":" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Time_in_Default.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

Meaning that the sub total I desire would be 157:49:52

Now when I use this expression

```
=(System.Math.Floor(Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value) / 3600) - System.Math.Floor(Sum(Fields!Time_in_Default.Value) / 3600)) & ":" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

It only subtracts the hour values which in this case would remove 5 hours, therefore only leaving me with a sub total of 158:02:38

Therefore how can I get the expression to also subtract the minutes and seconds to get the desired subtotal?

Comment: What is 163:02:38 - 163 hours, 2 minutes and 38 seconds?

If this is coming from SQL Server - what datatype is the field? string?

Comment: @BIDeveloper it's likely an integer value that represents _seconds_ as you'll notice he divides by 3600 to get hours and then uses `floor` to disregard the remainder which would be minutes and seconds.

Comment: Yes the 163:02:38 is 163 hours, 2 minutes and 38 seconds

It's coming from SQL Server and they are just pure numerical values in the database. 

Then they are converted into a time value using the floor function.

So the time values are correct, I just can't get a clean subtraction from them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution to building a large expression would be to add the following custom code to your report:

```
Public Function ConvertSecondsToTime(seconds As Integer) As String
    Dim ts as TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)
    return Floor(ts.TotalHours).ToString() + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString()
End Function
```

And use the custom code in an expression like so:

```
=code.ConvertSecondsToTime(Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value) - Sum(Fields!Time_in_Default.Value))
```

Your two fields are represented in *seconds*, so, rather than calculating and subtracting each unit of time (hours, minutes and seconds) separately and applying the custom format, subtract in seconds (which in your given example of 157:49:52 would be 568192 seconds) and then apply the custom format.

The `TimeSpan` class will take the seconds and convert that into units of time by calling `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`.

You may wonder why we use `TotalHours` instead of `Hours`. Keep in mind that TimeSpan hours are based on a 24-hour clock, so anything outside of that will be treated as *days*. In comparison, `TotalHours`
 as stated in [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN documentation represents:

> the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional hours.

In other words, it represents the *whole* time in decimal hours. This is comparable to how your current expression is calculating the hours, hence why we use `Floor(ts.TotalHours)` in the custom code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jonathon, very much appreciated. 

At what point would I add the custom code to my SSRS report to enable me to carry out the calculation?

Comment: @DanTracey you're most welcome. Are you asking where the custom code (written in Visual Basic) is placed in the report or how you use that custom code?

Comment: Morning Jonathon,

I would be interested to know as to where the custom code would be placed in the report

Comment: @DanTracey. In the Design View, right click on the whitespace surrounding the report and select 'Report Properties'. There's a Code tab in there and that's where you place the above code. For reference: [Add Code to a Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms156028.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much Jonathon

Comment: Code placed and it now works perfectly - thanks ever so much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the database you are far better doing any complex data handling on the database side.

1. It's faster to develop and easier to debug.
2. Assuming you present the data via a stored procedure or view it is faster to run as it is compiled.
3. It's easier to manage changes to the schema in the future.
4. The view or stored procedure (i.e. you calculation) can be used by others.

Therefore, however you are creating your dataset, I would present a further column called e.g. TimeDifference and pass this into SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

The math in your third code sample is flawed in two ways.  First, you are only subtracting the hours and completely disregarding the "minutes and seconds" subtraction.  Second, you are rounding the hours *before* doing the subtraction, which could cause off-by-one issues under certain circumstances.

To solve your particular circumstance, you could fix your following formula like so:

```
=(System.Math.Floor((Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value) - Sum(Fields!Time_in_Default.Value)) / 3600) & ":" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value) - Sum(Fields!Time_in_Default.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

Breaking this down into components:

1. Subtract `Time_in_default` from `Staffed_Time` and *then* determine the hour count.
2. Subtract the `Time_in_default` from `Staffed_Time` and display the minutes and seconds.

But, to make this even simpler, just use VisualBasic's `Strings.Format` for the whole piece and avoid the math altogether:

```
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value) - Sum(Fields!Time_in_Default.Value), "00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

That won't require any custom code and is reasonably easy to understand.

Comment: `=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value) - Sum(Fields!Time_in_Default.Value), "00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")`

This won't work as he's representing hours outside of a 24-hour clock. It would return 13:49:52 in the example given.

Comment: appreciate the input Aaron but Jonathan's custom code got the job done yesterday